# KeyVaultClient hangs at GetSecretAsync

Tags: c#, azure, asynchronous, task, azure-keyvault

I need to use the KeyVaultClient in a synchronous method. I have so far tried:

```
var result = Task.Run(async () => await kvClient.GetSecretAsync(keyUrl)).Result;
```

and

```
var result = Task.Run(() => kvClient.GetSecretAsync(keyUrl)).Result;
```

and

```
var result = kvClient.GetSecretAsync(keyUrl).Result;
```

but all of them hang and never return anything. I have also tried:

```
var secretTask = kvClient.GetSecretAsync(keyUrl);
secretTask.Start();
Task.WaitAll(secretTask);
var result = secretTask.Result;
```

but that gave me an error message on "Start()": `Start may not be called on a promise-style task.`

So then I tried:

```
var task = kvClient.GetSecretAsync(keyUrl);
task.RunSynchronously();
var result = task.Result;
```

Which threw the error: `RunSynchronously may not be called on a task not bound to a delegate, such as the task returned from an asynchronous method.`

What should I do? Similar questions on StackOverflow only led me to the above answers.

Comment: Well, you should call asynchronous functions in an asynchronous way. You have to use `await`

Comment: I can't. Unfortunately if I made this function async, and the function that called this function async, and followed the chain up, it ends at a constructor. I cannot use await here.

Comment: Well, that's the problem. Constructors cannot go launching background work nobody asked for. Use a static (called "factory") asynchronous method that gets the data and returns the instantiated object